Enhancing In-App Call Persistence: Allowing Users to Navigate Freely Without Interrupting Calls
My Request
I have an App that is live on the App Store and Play Store,  in my App it allows users to make a phone call to one another. I'm using livekit.io for the calling functionality. It is working well, user can hear each other, etc,
My Issues
When user A calls user B,  they both MUST  remain on the phone call page, once either one leaves the phone call page, the call will end,
What I Need
I need a solution such that even if the user goes over another page on the app or goes to another App they should still stay connected on the call just like WhatsApp
I used https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming which helps to awaken the user's device, but when I leave the app or minimize the App the call it's interrupted
